# I was extracting table from pdf using tabula. but it gives me TypeError

Tags: tabula

```
from tabula import read_pdf
df=read_pdf('AXIS BANK.pdf')
df
```

```
File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tabula/io.py:395, in read_pdf(input_path, output_format, encoding, java_options, pandas_options, multiple_tables, user_agent, use_raw_url, pages, guess, area, relative_area, lattice, stream, password, silent, columns, relative_columns, format, batch, output_path, force_subprocess, options)
    392     raise ValueError(f"{path} is empty. Check the file, or download it manually.")
    394 try:
--> 395     output = _run(
    396         tabula_options,
    397         java_options,
    398         path,
    399         encoding=encoding,
    400         force_subprocess=force_subprocess,
    401     )
    402 finally:
    403     if temporary:
```

at the end it says

Comment: Could you please provide the full error message ?